# Which visa should my aunt send for me to live in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, family, uk-visa, ethiopian-citizens

I am from Ethiopia, living in Saudi Arabia with my parents. My father's stepsister lives in the UK and she is a British citizen. My question is: Can she send me a visa to live with her forever (not tourist nor student visa) so I can complete my studies there? She agreed that she will support me.

If yes, which type of visa I should apply for? I am little confused because I am 16 years old. What should I do? She is ready to sponsor me.

Comment: Why not a student visa, if the primary intention is to study in the UK?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, I do think he states that he wishes to remain permanently in the UK.

Comment: Your aunt cannot **send** you a visa. You have to apply, and if the UK government agrees, they'll be doing the sending...

Comment: Why would you need to stay with her _forever_ to complete your studies in the UK?

Comment: You were unable to comment because you created a new account.  Your accounts are https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/13724/jafar-mohammed and https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/13728/jafar-mohammed.  You can [merge](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but there is no suitable visa that matches what you have asked for. The visa that might suit you is for study. Once you have completed your studies you may then be able to apply for a new visa for work.
The total cost will be tens of thousands of British pounds (over at least 5 years) because you will have to pay international student fees for your courses.
The UK government has relevant advice here https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/eligibility

Comment: I know the OP said not student visa, but it is the correct visa type if the intent is to complete studies in the UK.

Comment: Patricia Shanahan , the original question was primarily about living there forever, with studying as a secondary objective.

Answer (score 1):

*Want/don't want* and *can* often have little to do together, especially when it comes to immigration. You are under the impression that there has to be a visa for your needs/wants. Since you want to go to the UK to study (and, possibly, if they let you, to live there permanently), the first step is to apply for a student visa.

Getting permanent residence in the UK requires that you spend a few years (from 2 to 15, depending on your residence status) in the UK as a temporary resident **first**. You can't just be abroad, never having lived there, and hope for permanent residence. So you need to qualify first. Which means getting in the UK, hopefully on a legal basis. And in your case there isn't anything much outside a student visa. Especially at your age.

So my advice is, stop day-dreaming about what-ifs, and start looking into a student visa, and the costs, which, as mentioned in another answer, will be in the tens of thousands of GBP. And that's of course IF you can find a school that accepts you.